# Axios post entering catch block even after successful Rest API call completion

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

My axios post request is not returning the value returned by the API in a non success 401 scenario. It works fine when its a success scenario.

My reset Password API returns the status code, and a message for every call. when I use post man to test its output for resetting a password, giving incorrect current password, I get

Postman Output:

```js
 statusCode: 401,
            headers: {
               .......
               ........
            },
body: "{"code":"NotAuthorizedException","name":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"Incorrect username or password."}" <--- This is the body output
```

But in my axios post, it goes to the catch block:

```js
await Axios.post(resetAPIUrl, resetParams, config).then(value=> {
                    console.log(`Returned data ----> ${JSON.stringify(value)}`);
                    resolve(value);
                }).catch(error=>{
                    console.log(`Failing--->${error}`)
                    reject(error)
                });
```

this is the error that I am getting in the catch block of Axios post:

`Error: Request failed with status code 401`

The error reason is correct. But why isn it going into catch block? Its a successful completion of the process. Calling the API directly from post man gives me the correct output structure.

Comment: The title mentions it enters the catch block but your last sentence said it isn't going into the catch block. Which is actually happening here?

Comment: Oopps. My mistake. It is going into the catch block. I don't want it to go the catch blaock, and give me the API response.

Comment: Because axios by default only considers 2xx status codes to be successes.

Comment: Btw, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Oh didn't know that. Is there any way to get the exact API response in the catch block? The API resturns the status code, headers, and body even for all status codes.

Comment: If you want to handle 401s, in the error block you can add an `if (status === 401)` and work from there

Comment: @Bergi I would say it's more an issue of mixing `async/await` with Promise chaining than it is starting/constructing a Promise... `axios` handles that. OP could clearly just use a `try/catch` and await the response. That post is over 6 years old (!) and the landscape has shifted.

Comment: @DrewReese Mixing `await` with `then` might also be an issue, both those `resolve(value)` and `reject(error)` calls in the callbacks look suspiciously like the promise constructor antipattern. Yes, it's old, but still a mistake.

Comment: @Bergi Right, ok, I see now that `resolve`/`reject` are from another scope not included in the snippet.

Comment: Trying to use interceptors to handle 401. Didn't know that existed.

Comment: Hi @Bergi, yes the resolve/reject are for the promise which is for a different scope. The above snippets are in a reset function, that returns a promise

Answer (score 2):

Interceptor was the answer. Since Axios doesn't consider any response other than 200 as the success scenario, interceptors can be used to capture the other responses:

```js
{     
                Axios.interceptors.request.use(req=>{
                   console.log(`This is the request ---> ${req.method} ${req.url}`)
                   return req;
                })
                Axios.interceptors.response.use(res => {
                    console.log(`res status ---> ${res.status}`)
                    resolve(res)
                    return res;
                }, (error)=>{
                    console.log(`This is the error status ---> ${error.response.status}`)
                    if(error.response.status === 401){
                       resolve(error.response);
                    }
                })
                await Axios.post(resetAPIUrl, resetParams, config);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response code shows 200 then in your .then block you have some method or variable which is not defined. check for it!